# Linear algebra - product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am trying to solve this question;

The $2\times 2$ elementary matrix $E$ can be gotten from the identity matrix using the row operation R1 = r1 + 2 r2. Find $EA$ if 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 50\\ 51 \end{bmatrix}$$

($A$ is a $2\times1$ matrix)

I found the answer which is a $2\times 1$ matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}152\\
  51 \end{bmatrix}$$

But the answer for this question is a $2\times 2$ matrix. (The book says so)

Is the question wrong or I'm doing a mistake?

Thanks.

You may find the question below.

[image: question]

Comment: No, EA should be a 2x1 matrix, your answer seems correct.

Comment: Is it certain that the two two-digit numbers in $A$ aren't supposed to be four single digit numbers?

Comment: No they are not

Comment: Oh, I just realized thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some pretty terrible typesetting in the picture. I would totally interpret this as a $2\times 1$ matrix as well, the way it appears.

However, it is entirely possible this is just a display problem, and the matrix was actually meant to be $2\times 2$.

Amusingly, the answers either way are similar:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}5&0\\ 5&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}15&2\\ 5&1\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}50 \\ 51\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}152\\ 51\end{bmatrix}$$

It looks like you are analyzing the dimensions of the products of matrices correctly, so good job. I think the answer to this question entirely hinges upon asking the author what this is supposed to read. I'm betting it's just failed typesetting.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I couldn't understand  the spaces between the digits.

Comment: @oguzhandalgic And judging from the pic you sent, we totally understand why you thought the way you did :) They really do look like two numbers rather than four...